# SWRevealViewController rear view size

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have been using SWRevealViewController and so far its great.  I have a slide out panel on the right side and when open the rear view contents is sized to fill the full screen cutting some of the left hand side of the rear view off.  Is there a way to resize the rear view so it better fits the open space when the right menu is open?

I though I could just set the bounds such as

```
self.view.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: self.view.bounds.height)
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to resize your view . Hope it help !!

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth = UIScreen.main().bounds.size.width-70;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this resizes the actual reveal amount.  I need to resize the content of the actual rear view to fit in the gap map by the reveal